# Creating a String variable in JavaScript by comparing 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 JavaScript arrays like below;

```
arr1 = [CRS02,CRS04,CRS03,CRS01,CRS05];
arr2 = [CRS02,CRS03,CRS05];
```

`arr2` contain less than or equal elements than `arr1`.

I want to create a string like below.

```
CRS02,--,CRS03,--,CRS05
```

If elements in `arr2` inclide in `arr1`, should show the element else should show "--".

I tried as below,

```
for (a = 0; a < arr1.length; a++) {
    for (c = 0; c < arr2.length; c++) {
        if (arr1[a] == arr2[c]) {
            content +=  arr2[c] + ",";
            continue;
        } else {
            content += "--,";
        }
    }
   continue;
}

    alert(content);
```

But not working correctly. Please help.

Comment: Should this `if (arr1[a] == applied_courses[c])` be `if (arr1[a] == arr2[c])`?

Comment: @Ward sorry my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

- *Array* items are sorted (if not, you need to sort them)
- `arr2` doesn't contain any element which is not part of `arr1`

Use `map` to iterate and check if `index` of each `item` is not `-1`

```
var output = arr1.map( s => arr2.indexOf( s ) != -1 ? s : "--" );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr1 = ["CRS02","CRS04","CRS03","CRS01","CRS05"];
var arr2 = ["CRS02","CRS03","CRS05"];
var output = arr1.map( s => arr2.indexOf( s ) != -1 ? s : "--" );
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems like you have filled the arrays with vars.
Strings in JavaScript start and end with single (`''`) or double (`""`) quotes.
I will assume they are strings in terms of simplicity.

You don't need two loops for that. Just use a `step` counter:

**Note**: The aim of this solution is to be readable, in order for you to catch the concept. Of course, it can be implemented using `indexOf` or `reduce` as suggested in other answers.

```js
var arr1 = ["CRS02","CRS04","CRS03","CRS01","CRS05"];
var arr2 = ["CRS02","CRS03","CRS05"];

var content = "";

// Use length of largest array.
for (var i = 0, step = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
    if (arr1[i] == arr2[step]) {
        content +=  arr1[i] + ", ";
        ++step;
    } else {
        content += "--, ";
    }
}

// Remove last comma and space.
content = content.substring(0, content.length - 2);

console.log(content);
```

Comment: `This is not the most efficient solution.` Nope. This is an efficient solution. All the other solution uses an `indexOf` inside. Its a costlier operation.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Less 'fancy' would be a better word for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = ["CRS02","CRS04","CRS03","CRS01","CRS05"];
var arr2 = ["CRS02","CRS03","CRS05"];

var str = "";
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
  if(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) >= 0){
    str += arr1[i] + ",";
  }
  else{
    str += "--"+",";
  }
}
str = str.substring(0,(str.length-1));
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var arr1 = ["CRS02","CRS04","CRS03","CRS01","CRS05"];
var arr2 = ["CRS02","CRS03","CRS05"];

function getContainsString(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.reduce(function(result, el) {
        return result + (arr2.indexOf(el) < 0 ? "--" : el) + ",";
    }, "").slice(0, -1);
}

console.log(getContainsString(arr1, arr2));
//CRS02,--,CRS03,--,CRS05
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data sets are large and you don't want to use `indexOf` repeatedly in the loop, you can use a `Set` to quickly check the contents of `arr2`:

```js
const arr1 = ["CRS02","CRS04","CRS03","CRS01","CRS05"];
const set2 = new Set(["CRS02","CRS03","CRS05"]);

console.log(
  arr1
    .map(x => set2.has(x) ? x : "--")
    .join(",")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` to iterate through `arr1` and use `array#includes` to test the existence of value in `arr2`.

```js
var arr1 = ["CRS02","CRS04","CRS03","CRS01","CRS05"],
    arr2 = ["CRS02","CRS03","CRS05"],
    result = arr1.map(v => arr2.includes(v) ? v :'--')
                 .join(',');
console.log(result);
```